# Responsive form with aligned inputs and labels

Tags: html, css, responsive

Im trying to create a simple responsive form. Here's what i have now:

```css
.content {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}
.form-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  gap: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.field-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
}
.input-label {
  width: 70px;
}
input {
  width: 130px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="form-wrapper">
    <div class="field-wrapper">
      <label class="input-label">Name</label>
      <input></input>
    </div>
    <div class="field-wrapper">
      <label class="input-label">Address</label>
      <input></input>
    </div>
    <div class="field-wrapper">
      <label class="input-label">Nationality</label>
      <input></input>
    </div>
    <div class="field-wrapper">
      <label class="input-label">Relatsionship</label>
      <input></input>
    </div>
    <div class="field-wrapper">
      <label class="input-label">Age</label>
      <input></input>
    </div>
    <div class="field-wrapper">
      <label class="input-label">Gender</label>
      <input></input>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/0xjcstzy/

This works, all inputs are aligned and stay aligned in columns when they get wrapped.
But its not what i want, i would like to get rid of the empty wasted space between the label and input in columns so labels would still be aligned, inputs will be still aligned but the widths of label + input would vary in columns based on the longest label in that column.

Here's a photo of the end result what i would like to achieve:
[image]

Comment: Flexbox is not the optimal solution here, unless using fixed widths. Frankly CSS-Grid/CSS-Tables would be ideal here.

Comment: Also, you have a 70px hardset width on all your labels, that's your culprit for this specific scenario.

Comment: If i remove the fixed width on the label then anything wont be aligned in columns anymore.

Comment: i think you should use css-grid for this

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using a fixed width for the label.

I would go and use CSS grid here. You can use fractional widths to control the width of the labels and inputs (although I'm sure you could do with others e.g. percentage etc.).

Here's what the code below will produce:
[image]

```css
.content {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
}

.form-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 20px;
}

.field-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="form-wrapper">
    <div class="field-wrapper">
      <label class="input-label">Name</label>
      <input></input>
    </div>
    <div class="field-wrapper">
      <label class="input-label">Address</label>
      <input></input>
    </div>
    <div class="field-wrapper">
      <label class="input-label">Nationality</label>
      <input></input>
    </div>
    <div class="field-wrapper">
      <label class="input-label">Relationship</label>
      <input></input>
    </div>
    <div class="field-wrapper">
      <label class="input-label">Age</label>
      <input></input>
    </div>
    <div class="field-wrapper">
      <label class="input-label">Gender</label>
      <input></input>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My example with fixed widths was more  like a starting point to show the structure i have at the moment.
Your solution works but is not really what i was looking for, it produces nice even colums and is responsive but i was looking for a solution where all columns would not be all same width. I would like them wo be the width of the longest label + input width. I am not sure if that is possible, but thats why im asking :D